# Reverse Proxy to Apache to Nextcloud / The port is incorrectly being inserted into the URL

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I feel that my problem is somewhere in the nextcloud setup, or the apache setup that routes to it, but I will put everything on the table here just in case I'm mistaken.

My router accepts requests via port 443, which forwards it to a Docker NGINX Proxy Manager, which routes it to Apache on port 4432, which connects to nextcloud.

**Router:443 > NGINX > Apache:4432 > Nextcloud**

The problem is that when I enter the URL (https://nc.myserver.com/nextcloud), the URL is being rewritten with the port that the reverse proxy is supposed to do in the background.

**So, I type this: https://nc.myserver.com/nextcloud**

**And it turns my URL to: https://nc.myserver.com:4432/nextcloud/ (which fails to load any page)**

Then, I manually remove the port from that URL, and it automatically forwards me to a working URL: https://nc.myserver.com/nextcloud/index.php/login

[image: image of URLs]

I have several other functioning reverse proxied sites. This one is the only one that I have any issue with. It's also the only one that goes through NGINX to Apache.

Between Apache and Nextcloud there are several config and .htaccess files and it seems like it could be any one of these causing the issue, but so far I cannot track it down.

Based on how I described the issue, can anyone identify where they think the problem is occurring?

Comment: I just discovered that the a trailing slash on the URL gets it to go to the right place. So, `https://nc.myserver.com/nextcloud/` works as expected.